# how to set custom icon, which is in my local system to react-native-hamburger

Tags: react-native

```
    <Drawer some_styles>
        <View >
            <Hamburger active={this.state.menuActive} 
                onPress={this._handleMenuButtonPress}/>
        </View>
    </Drawer>
```

I have to use .svg image as icon of hamburger instead of predefined icon.How to set our own image to hamburger. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this article](https://medium.com/bam-tech/add-custom-icons-to-your-react-native-application-f039c244386c) to help me include custom icons. I will briefly summarise the steps:

1. Install react-native-vector-icons, this is a library which allows you to add custom icons alongside their standard built-in icons (which are already great btw).
2. Convert your SVG icon(s) to a font (.tff file), Fontello or Icomoon are online tools supported by rn-vector-icons which allow you to do just that
3. Add that font to your project
4. Create a small config file where you tell rn-vector-icons which font needs to be linked

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But I need to set the icon in hamburger. But hamburger provides default icons.I have to change that default and set my icons in hamburger. But in <hamburger > am not getting any properties to set the icon. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hamburger